# How to get the length of a hex number in a text file

Tags: python, hex, text-files, readlines

I have a number of text files with a single long hex number inside each file. I want to find out the length of each hex number, i.e. ['FFFF0F'] =6, ['A23000000000000FD'] =17.

i read the file in:

```
file_to_open = open(myFile , 'r')
filey = file_to_open.readlines()

print(type(filey))
a = hex(int(filey, 16))
print(type(a))


n = len(filey)
print('length = ', n)
```

And my error is:

```
TypeError: int() cannot convert non-string with explicit base
```

if I remove the base 16 I get the error:

```
TypeError : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Any ideas on how to just read in the number and find how many hex digits it contains?

Comment: Please share a snippet of your file

Comment: ['00FF91203225000000000000000000...04A201F201A301A2010000\n']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines` returns `list` of `str`s (lines) - in case of one-line file it is list with one element. Use `read` to get whole text as single `str`, `strip` leading and trailing whitespaces, then just get `len`:

```
with open(myFile , 'r') as f:
    filey = f.read()
filey = filey.strip()
n = len(filey)
```

Note also that I used `with` so I do not have to care about closing that file handle myself. I assume all your files are single-line and contain some hex number. Note that if your number has any leading `0`s, they will be counted too, so for example length of `000F` is 4.